# How can I create path based logo with animation in Android?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am new to Android Animations. Currently, I need to create splash screen with animated logo. Like [`this example`](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/bGyoz). My minimum API level is 11. I am in trouble, absolutely. There are any third-party libs or offical way? Please help!

Comment: on a scale of 1 to 100 how good are you in math?

Comment: Sorry for late response. I think not bad in math. But, what is relation between scaling and my question? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout these following libraries that will do the work you are seeking for :

1. [Android Path View](https://github.com/geftimov/android-pathview)
2. [Animated Path View](https://github.com/matthewrkula/AnimatedPathView)

   [image: Android Path View]

**Romain Guy** also posted a blog to implement Path View Animation :
http://www.curious-creature.org/2013/12/21/android-recipe-4-path-tracing/